# Contradictions with the word 'same'

Tags: identity, presocratics

We know in Language we have an affinity for the word 'Same', I've noticed that when we used it with respect to objects and people, my question is whether this is a particular problem with definition in our language or a greater idea involving how we deal with change over time.

The best example I have of this is the pre-socratic phrase about not being able to enter 'the same river twice', in our natural language we would refer to any river with the same name as 'the same river' even though it's properties change we accept that something can be the same 'object' even though its properties can change, whereas this suggests that due to the change in the river (water flowing) and the changed in the individual entering the river, the same person cannot enter the same river twice, this time the river being the 'same' is about not changing instead of having some sense of identity that we provide.

People are the best example of this, we may say that we've had the 'same boss' for the last ten years, but at the same time someone who has experienced change due to age or personal development may say that they aren't 'the same' as they were, or may take this further and say they aren't 'the same person they were' and hence my boss for the last ten years cannot be 'the same boss' as they have changed in this context due to aging in this time.

Comment: See the so-called [Ship of Theseus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus) problem.

Comment: And see [Personal Identity](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/identity-personal/)

Comment: yeah, the ship of Theseus really is the essence of this question how do we define identity of things, thanks for that.

Comment: As usual, in metaphysical issues, there are several perspectives: the river is the same, also if water changes, and also when the river bed changes... A person is identical the day after: it bears the same name, etc.

Comment: There is a standard distinction made here between *numerical identity* (vs. distinctness) and *qualitative similarity* (vs. difference). Do you mean to suggest that a person (say a boss) who has matured or weathered or otherwise changed through the last 10 years is not only no longer *similar* to the way they were 10 years ago (many people aren't), but actually is a *numerically distinct* person, i.e. that there are literally 2 distinct people that you're talking about when you talk about before and after, not just 1 person who has changed in qualities over time? If so, why?

Comment: Some of it perhaps is just the way people talk, the thing with the word 'same' is that it means 'not different', I'm not sure if we can talk about numerical identity easily with different times, but we can say that a person is not numerically identical with a previous version of themselves as they do not have all properties in common, I'm not sure you can talk about two numerically different people because they cannot physically exist together, we often hear though that someone is a 'different person' to who they were before though, perhaps we should talk about 'in properties' and 'in sense'.

Comment: @user1007028: *but we can say that a person is not numerically identical with a previous version of themselves as they do not have all properties in common* Well, so the point is to ask whether "having all properties in common" throughout multiple times is a reasonable standard for determining for/against numerical identity. If you have a banana on the counter that is unripe on Monday, and a banana on the counter that is ripe on Tuesday, and a banana on the counter that is mushy on Wednesday, is that (by itself) a reason to conclude that you have 3 distinct bananas?

Comment: Or just 1 banana changing in qualities over time, with the (non-conflicting, because they are time-indexed) properties (i) unripe-on-Monday, (ii) ripe-on-Tuesday, (iii) mushy-on-Wednesday?

Comment: Of course, we'd say that we just have one banana, that's my point though, sometimes we talk as if there's one object going through change, yet, sometimes we talk as if the change makes it almost an entirely different object 'unable to step into the same river twice', some of it is the way we discuss things some of it is just the word 'same' which is vague unfortunately.

Comment: @AlabamaScholiast - Correct; in terms of "properties" the banana has changed: thus it is not "the same". But, at the same time, I think that we cannot eat it twice: thus, it is "one".

Comment: This is a typical "philosophical conundrum": every baby learn quite early (without language and other stuff) to recognize is mother and also when he changes clothing and combing... Thus, there is a quite natural "perception of identity".

Comment: I think it is quite hard to explain, we know it, I think it does not help that we use the one word to talk about perhaps two different perspectives of the one idea, perhaps if we were more precise in how we talk about things, for example if an object changes, it is the same essence, but not 'the same object' and we only use 'same object' for when things have exactly the same properties and the same essence I think I read about the river example saying that if we define there to be one river, whose identity is based entirely on it's source, where it goes through we can be more precise.

Comment: The colloquial use of 'same' such as your example of 'same boss' really is by social and linguistic convention, metaphysically it may very well not be the case at all. During the past 10 years there might be a lot happened to your company plus aging such that your boss's view about certain metric of employee performance may be changed, thus you might act accordingly per such subtle observation of *non-sameness* against linguistic convention...

Comment: I think so, the use of 'same' in the river example which was referenced by the pre-socratics might be a little bit ambiguous, is it using 'same' in the way we commonly do when saying 'the same x' or is it saying, that it is impossible for an identical person to enter an identical river twice (due to the change in both the person and rivers state)

Comment: For me this Heraclitus's statement means the more finer time-dependent model River(t), due to time arrow's spontaneous ticking and passing, River(t1) never exactly equals River(t2) when t2 is not equal t1 as it's already common ancient knowledge physical objects subject to changes all the time. "*What wrinkles is subject to change. What does not wrinkle does not change.*" from the ancient [Shurangama sutra](http://www.cttbusa.org/shurangama/shurangama6.asp.html) which also talked about King Prasenajit saw the Ganges Rivers at different times of his life...

Comment: in this case, 'same' is about state not being then.

Comment: [State](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_of_affairs_(philosophy)) is a core metaphysic notion: *a state of affairs is a truth-maker, whereas a proposition is a truth-bearer. Whereas states of affairs either obtain or fail-to-obtain, propositions are either true or false. Some philosophers understand the term "states of affairs" in a more restricted sense as a synonym for "fact". In this sense, there are no states of affairs that do not obtain. David Armstrong is well known for his defense of a factualism, a position according to which the world is a world of facts and not a world of things*